# iOS App Development choice in Certificates greyed out

Tags: ios, applications, development

I am new to iOS App Development and my account type is individual. I already created 2 apps with valid dev certificates(unexpired as they are still new created this April) but when I create a 3rd app and added a 3rd development certificate under Certificates tab in memberscenter, the iOS App Development choice is greyed out.

I tried revoking the previous 2 certificates because I can create new ones later anyway, and fortunately, I was able to create a certificte for my 3rd app. Now, I wanted to add again the certificates of the previous 2 apps, but then, the iOS App Development choice is greyed out again.

Any help? I'm new to this.

FYI, when I requested a certificate from a certificate authority in keychain, I am using my developer email and saved it to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my mistake. I got it working now. I only use 1 certificate for all my apps - the one I requested on the Certificate Assistance on Keychain menu, and generated unique provisioning profiles for each app.